# How to position a div at the bottom of another with using an absolute property

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position

JSX:

```
<div className="card">
      <div className="inner">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="title">
            <Link to={`/product/${_id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </div>

          <div className="img">
            <img src={image} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card-price">
          <div className="price">{displayPrice(price)}</div>
          <div className="cart float-right">
            <ShoppingCart size={28} className="shopping-icon" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Rating rating={rating} numReviews={numReviews} />
        <hr className="descriptionBreak" data-content="About" />
        <div className="card-footer">
          <p className="description">{shortDescription}</p>
          <div className="label-container">
            {labels?.map((label, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="label">
                {label}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```css
.label-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.label {
    padding: 0.4em 1.3em;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #FFEAF6;
    color:#C62A82;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.inner {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[image: Image of cards]

As you can see from the image above, the cards line up, but I would like the labels to be placed equally from the bottom for each card, and at the moment the descriptions finish at different points causing the whitespace to be under the labels, instead of on top. If I use absolute positioning, then there is a problem with overlapping text at certain points, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try `display:flex` and make it a `flex-direction:column`, then use `space-between` on the `justify-content` for the card div.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. That works!

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` and set the direction to `flex-direction:column` to set the direction as a column, then use `space-between` on the `justify-content` for your card div. This will push the lower elements in the column to the bottom.